# drop down menu open upward

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to open drop down menu on upward, I am using jquery atocomplete, normally when we check autocomplete drop-down box open onward, but I want that should be open upward for that I tried this:--

```
     open:function(event,ui){
     var autocomplete = $(".ui-autocomplete");
     var oldTop = autocomplete.offset().top;
     console.log("oldtop"+oldTop);
     var newTop = oldTop - autocomplete.height() - ("#author").height() - 10;
    console.log("newTop"+newTop);
    autocomplete.css("top", newTop);

   },
```

when I used that code option open in upward but problem is that when suppose in auto-complete have only one result then white space show between search-box and result :

[image]

Comment: seems to be the issue with heigh, that might be static instead of auto!!

Comment: @cracker  if give height auto its look like that :- http://postimg.org/image/a5hzh89pz/8fef4ad8/

Comment: could you please create some demo, there might be more then one reason.

Comment: @cracker https://jsfiddle.net/tn7bx594/1/

Comment: try this $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ source: availableTags,   position: {  collision: "flip"  }
    });  and remove .ui-autocomplete class from your css.